# Meteor JS simulate server command line on client html

Tags: shell, meteor

I am new to Meteor and want to make a simple app. I am failing to simulate the command line on the server side according to http://terokaisti.blogspot.com/2012/10/writing-terminal-app-with-meteor-js.html

The result is just blank when on the client side (Mac OSX Mavericks) I type in a command and hit the "Run" button. I am using the exact code from the site above, except that I have autorun and exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;

Below are my html and js files...

TerminalApp.html

```
<head>
  <title>MeteorJS terminal</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> terminal}}
</body>

<template name="terminal">
 <pre>{{ window }}</pre>
<input id="command" type="text" value="{{ last_cmd }}" />
 <input type="button" value="Run" />
</template>
```

TerminalApp.js

```
// A collection for stdouts
var Replies = new Meteor.Collection('replies');

if(Meteor.is_client) {

 // Start listening changes in Replies
    Meteor.autorun(function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('replies');
    });

 // Set an observer to be triggered when Replies.insert() is invoked
 Replies.find().observe({
  'added': function(item) {
   // Set the terminal reply to Session
   Session.set('stdout', item.message);
  }
 });

 // Show the last command in input field
 Template.terminal.last_cmd = function() {
 return Session.get('last_cmd');
 };

 // Show the last shell reply in browser
 Template.terminal.window = function() {
  return Session.get('stdout');
 };

 // Add an event listener for Run-button
 Template.terminal.events = {
  'click [type="button"]': function() {
   var cmd = $('#command').val();
   Session.set('last_cmd', cmd);

   // Call the command method in server side
   Meteor.call('command', cmd);
  }
 }; 
}

if(Meteor.is_server) {
 var exec;

 // Initialize the exec function
 Meteor.startup(function() {
  exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;
 });

 // Trigger the observer in Replies collection
    Meteor.publish('replies', function() {
        return Replies.find();
    });

 Meteor.methods({
  'command': function(line) {
   // Run the requested command in shell
   exec(line, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // Collection commands must be executed within a Fiber
    Fiber(function() {
     Replies.remove({});
     Replies.insert({message: stdout ? stdout : stderr});
    }).run();
   });
  }
 });
}
```

What am I missing? How can I debug? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example. The output will be in terminal. Hope that helps.

terminal.html

```
<head>
  <title>terminal</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <input type="text" id="command">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

terminal.js

```
Replies = new Meteor.Collection('replies');


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to terminal.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click #button': function () {
      console.log("clicking");
      var cmd = $("input#command").val();
      console.log("command", cmd);
      var replyId = Meteor.call('command', cmd);
      Session.set('replyId', replyId);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;
  Meteor.methods({
    'command' : function(line) {
      console.log("In command method", line);
      Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
      exec(line, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('Command Method', error, stdout, stderr);
        Fiber(function() {
          Replies.remove({});
          var replyId = Replies.insert({message: stdout ? stdout : stderr});
          return replyId;  
        }).run();
      }); 
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the fibers npm module directly, we now have Meteor.bindEnvironment as stated here:

[Future.wait() can't wait without a fiber (while waiting on another future in Meteor.method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346847/future-wait-cant-wait-without-a-fiber-while-waiting-on-another-future-in-met/18347076#18347076)

and here:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/renderable_content